# How do I properly exit prematurely from a method returning Task?

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-identity, smtpclient

I have a method that returns Task, in particular it is the `SendAsync` method of the `IIdentityMessageService`.

Now, I know how to use `client.SendAsync()` as a direct way of doing it. But my problem with it is that my interface `SendAsync` method performs other checks and validations. If everything is okay it would call `smtpClient.SendAsync` and am done.

But as I mentioned the method performs checks and validations and if something improper is found what sort of return signature should I use? and is there a way to retrieve error information in that case?

For something as clear as that there shouldn't be a need for code but if you need to visualize it then here it is what I mean...

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService 
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message) 
    {
         SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();                 
         if (everythingIsOkay)
         {
             return smtp.SendEmailAsync();   // (BBBB)
         }
         else  // something is not right
         {
               // <= THIS IS WHAT I NEED  (AAAA)                
         }
    }
}
```

For what I see the `AccountController` uses `await` so it waits for the task to complete but then how would I -within the `AccountController`- get the result of whether it terminated due to AAAA or BBBB ?

Comment: Without code it's hard to understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: Do you just want to return a failed task? You can use [`Task.FromException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823325.aspx)

Comment: So what do you want the code to do?  Without knowing what you want to have happen, we can't tell you how to make it happen.

Comment: @Servy read the "How would I..." part of the post.

Answer (score 2):

Well, how would you do it if the code was synchronous?

```
public void Send(IdentityMessage message)
{
   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
   // some stuff here to configure SmtpClient
   if (everythingIsOkay)
      smtp.SendEmail();
   else  // something is not right
      ???
}
```

Probably like this:

```
public void Send(IdentityMessage message)
{
   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
   // some stuff here to configure SmtpClient
   if (everythingIsOkay)
      smtp.SendEmail(); // throws an exception on error
   else  // something is not right
      throw new ConfigurationException(...);
}
```

So, you do it asynchronously the same way:

```
public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
   // some stuff here to configure SmtpClient
   if (everythingIsOkay)
      await smtp.SendEmailAsync(); // throws an exception on error
   else  // something is not right
      throw new ConfigurationException(...);
}
```

Comment: is there anything to be gained here by `await`ing `SendEmailAsync()`, or could we just remove the `async`?

Comment: @kai: Yes, it (asynchronously) waits for the email to be sent, and will raise any exceptions if there were errors sending it.

Comment: yes, but couldn't we just return the task and let the client `await` it?

Comment: @kai: Returning the task directly changes how the `ConfigurationException` is handled; it is raised directly on the calling thread instead of being placed on the returned task. If the new semantics match the desired semantics, then yes.

Comment: @stephen-cleary What I did before the async was that I JSONed an object with two properties back. One property is a boolean indicating success or not, and the other a string with the error message in case the first property is false. Then the client would use this information to show the message without crapping out with an exception. That is what I want to accomplish here